# How to use the github koans java to learn java in MAC OS?

Tags: java, eclipse

As a Java beginner, I downloaded the zip file of [java-koans](https://github.com/matyb/java-koans) for learning purposes.
When I tried to import the file to Eclipse, some alerts came up - such as:
`cannot be resolved to a type.`

So how to resolve this problem? or if I made mistakes, how can I utilize these file for better learning?

Comment: Did you read the README? https://github.com/matyb/java-koans/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes. i tried to execute the run.sh in terminal.

Comment: I don't believe that eclipse ever told you `cannot be resolved to a type` without naming some class or identifier. Furthermore, those koans look less like a valid eclipse project, and more like something you should do using a simple text editor.

Comment: I'm using an IntelliJ for them but was given a Maven archetype that set the project up for us.